# Using perf from a user account

Tags: linux, security, kernel, perf

I'm following [admin-guide/perf-security.html](https://docs.kernel.org/admin-guide/perf-security.html) from the kernel docs to set up perf with a user account. Briefly, I set up the capabilities on the binary and change group ownership to `perf_users`. However my user does not seem to be able to use perf.

From using `perf stat $(which ls)` on Debian bookworm I get the error:

```
Error:
Access to performance monitoring and observability operations is limited.
Consider adjusting /proc/sys/kernel/perf_event_paranoid setting to open
access to performance monitoring and observability operations for processes
without CAP_PERFMON, CAP_SYS_PTRACE or CAP_SYS_ADMIN Linux capability.
More information can be found at 'Perf events and tool security' document:
https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/perf-security.html
perf_event_paranoid setting is 3:
  -1: Allow use of (almost) all events by all users
      Ignore mlock limit after perf_event_mlock_kb without CAP_IPC_LOCK
>= 0: Disallow raw and ftrace function tracepoint access
>= 1: Disallow CPU event access
>= 2: Disallow kernel profiling
To make the adjusted perf_event_paranoid setting permanent preserve it
in /etc/sysctl.conf (e.g. kernel.perf_event_paranoid = <setting>)
```

I have attempted to research this issue online but all the answers mention modifying `perf_event_paranoid`, which according to perf-security.html is for unprivileged users, whereas the `perf_users` group is supposed to be the privileged users. [A question on unix.stackexchange about perf user accounts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/642374/how-to-run-linux-perf-without-root), exactly like mine, has not been answered.

**To replicate**:

From a root shell, create the `perf_users` group and modify the perf binary to modify its group ownership and prevent access from others:

```
PERFBIN=$(which perf)
groupadd perf_users
chgrp perf_users $PERFBIN
chmod o-rxw $PERFBIN
```

Now enable capabilities on the binary,

```
setcap "cap_perfmon,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep" $PERFBIN
setcap -v "cap_perfmon,cap_sys_ptrace,cap_syslog=ep" $PERFBIN
getcap $PERFBIN
```

Finally, either add a user to `perf_users` group with `usermod -a -G perf_users $USER` or add an `/etc/sudoers.d/perf` file with contents `$USER     ALL = (: perf_users) $PERFBIN` and use as `sudo -g perf_users perf stat $(which ls)`